# Promotion of integer in variadic functions

Tags: c, variadic-functions, signed, unsigned-integer, integer-promotion

Why does the first `f()` call in the code below end up printing the `-2` that I have passed to it as `4294967294` instead?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(int64_t i, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int64_t j;

    va_start(ap, i);
    j = va_arg(ap, int64_t);
    printf("%jd %jd\n", (intmax_t) i, (intmax_t) j);
    va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
    f(-1, -2);           // Prints -1 4294967294 (bug!)
    f(-1, (int64_t) -2); // Prints -1 -2 (fix!)
    return 0;
}
```

I can understand why the second `f()` call with the fix works. But I can't understand why the first `f()` call causes this issue. Can you explain this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first call, the argument is passed as an `int`. Unless `int` is represented by using 64 bits, you invoke undefined behavior by trying to extract a `int64_t` from it. Judging by the output from your program `int` is not presented using 64 bits on your platform.

From the **Section 7.16.1.1/2** C11 Standard (emphasis mine):

> The `va_arg` macro expands to an expression that has the specified type and the value of the next argument in the call. The parameter `ap` shall have been initialized by the `va_start` or `va_copy` macro (without an intervening invocation of the `va_end`). Each invocation of the `va_arg` macro modifies `ap` so that the values of successive arguments are returned in turn. The parameter type shall be a type name specified such that the type of a pointer to an object that has the specified type can be obtained simply by postfixing a * to type. **If there is no actual next argument, or if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according
> to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined,** except for the following cases:
>
> — one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
>
> — one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character type.